# Using vieta’s formula to make a cubic using roots

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, roots, cubics

Sorry for formatting issues as I’m on my phone.

The question is: the cubic equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ has roots $α$ , $β$, and $γ$. Find a cubic equation that has roots $1/α$ , $1/β$ and $1/γ$.

The only way I can see how to do it using Vietas formula is doing 1/-b/a , 1/c/a and so forth, but I don’t think that’s the correct way to do it so I’d like some guidance.

Comment: Do you know how to do a change of roots $  x \rightarrow \frac{1}{z}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $d\neq0$ it's just $$a\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3+b\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+c\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+d=0$$ or $$dx^3+cx^2+bx+a=0.$$
Indeed, since $\alpha$ is root of the equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$, so
$$a\alpha^3+b\alpha^2+c\alpha+d=0$$ or
$$a\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^3+b\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)^2+c\left(\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\alpha}}\right)+d=0,$$
which says that $\frac{1}{\alpha}$ is a root of the equation 
$$a\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^3+b\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+c\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+d=0.$$
Similarly, for $\frac{1}{\beta}$ and for $\frac{1}{\gamma}.$

By the Viete's theorem we obtain the same result:
$$\alpha+\beta+\gamma=-\frac{b}{a},$$
$$\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma=\frac{c}{a}$$ and $$\alpha\beta\gamma=-\frac{d}{a}.$$
Thus, $$\frac{1}{\alpha}+\frac{1}{\beta}+\frac{1}{\gamma}=\frac{\alpha\beta+\alpha\gamma+\beta\gamma}{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\frac{\frac{c}{a}}{-\frac{d}{a}}=-\frac{c}{d},$$
$$\frac{1}{\alpha\beta}+\frac{1}{\beta\gamma}+\frac{1}{\gamma\alpha}=\frac{\alpha+\beta+\gamma}{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\frac{-\frac{b}{a}}{-\frac{d}{a}}=\frac{b}{d}$$ and $$\frac{1}{\alpha\beta\gamma}=\frac{1}{-\frac{d}{a}}=-\frac{a}{d}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Right, so I didn’t have to use Vieta’s formula for this?

Comment: @user282938 Using of Vieta’s formulas gives the same result, but the reasoning, which I posted is simpler.

Comment: Would you be able to give me some guidance on how to use Vieta’s formula to achieve the same answer? I would appreciate it!

Comment: @user282938 I added something. See now.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: put $x = 1/y$ in your original cubic polynomial and then multiply the resulting rational function by $y^3$. This gives you another cubic polynomial: what are its roots?

Comment: I got a+by+cy^2+dy^2 as the cubic, is that correct?

Comment: Not quite. You should have $3$ as the last exponent.

Comment: That was a typo, sorry!